# I can't connect external monitor through hdmi port to my notebook

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have [MSI ex623](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/EX623.html#?div=Specification), I want to connect an external monitor through its HDMI port, 
but when I connect it nothing happens.

[image: Reduced since image of the relevant control panel]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do basic trouble shooting? E.g. does the monitor wok on another laptop (goal: determine if the monitor is broken). Does it work with another cable? Is the cable plugged in at both sides? Is the monitor powered on? ...

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: @vonbrand win7 x64